# Overriding the CSS of an existing library

Tags: html, css

I am using this library https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker to add emojis to my chat. I want to style the div with the class of .emojiPicker but it has inline styling which I can't seem to override. I've tried to find the html code to remove that styling but I can't find it and I can't find another way around it.
Does anyone have any idea how I could style the emojiPicker or where I can find the html to remove the inline styling?

Comment: This sounds like an `!important` job!

Comment: have you tried `!important` rule? Like: `h1{color: red !important}`

Comment: tried that, doesn't work

Comment: Could you share the code including .emojiPicker?

Comment: For some reason !important suddenly worked. Must have been some sort of  other issue combined with it before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best option but you can use the `!important` here:

```css
.a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.b {
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
  background: red !important;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a" style="border: 1px solid red; background: blue;">
  1234
</div>
<div class="b" style="border: 1px solid red; background: blue;">
  5678
</div>
```

In the second box the usage of `!important` made sure we can override the inline css.

Comment: [**CSS Specificity**](http://cssspecificity.com/) really great overview of CSS specificity.

Comment: @KilianStinson thanks :) I know it, there are also other resources

Comment: great explanation. It seems like I have some other issue because it partly works but this definitely explained it.

Comment: @Naomi you are welcome. If you include a problematic example it will be easier to help.